# Stackdriver Error reporting for Ruby, running on GKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stackdriver, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-iam

**Which steps are required to collect errors from a Rails app running on GKE?**

I have added the stackdriver gem to my Rails app and I have created a custom role with the `errorreporting.errorEvents.create` permission.
That role is given to the **Compute Engine default service account**

I interpret [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setup/ruby) that one does not have to do the following setup when running on GKE:

```
# Add this to config/environments/*.rb
Rails.application.configure do |config|
  # Stackdriver Error Reporting specific parameters
  config.google_cloud.error_reporting.project_id = "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
  config.google_cloud.error_reporting.keyfile    = "/path/to/service-account.json"
end
```

**I manually created an exception**

That gave me valuable information:

```
irb(main):001:0> Google::Cloud::ErrorReporting.report Exception.new(msg: "from console")
=> nil
irb(main):002:0> {:msg=>"from console"} (Exception)
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: 7:Stackdriver Error Reporting API has not been used in project NNNNN before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/overview?project=NNNN then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
```

After enabling the API, then I get this error:

```
irb(main):004:0> {:msg=>"from console"} (Exception)
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: 7:User not authorized.
```

So, which permission do I have to give to which user to make this work? :-|

Answer (score 2):

This seems permission issue, so after installing and configuring [google-cloud-ruby](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-error_reporting).

Then, you need to Enable the Stackdriver Error Reporting API.

Then you need to add the role "roles/errorreporting.writer" to the default  compute service account.

gcloud container clusters create example-cluster-name --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

When you create the cluster you need to add  --scope flag for platform see above an example:

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the relationship between scope and permissions? Why do we need both?