# Which service account are my pods running as by default?

Tags: service-accounts, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

When I have created a cluster with some nodes on GKE, which user does Google interpret my requests as coming from?
E.g. if I open a console on one of the nodes and do an API call to the Stackdriver API. Which user does the API think I am?

```
$ kubectl exec -it my-app bash
$ rails c
irb(main):005:0* Google::Cloud::ErrorReporting.report \
                 Exception.new(msg: "from console")
=> nil
irb(main):006:0> {:msg=>"from console"} (Exception)
Google::Cloud::PermissionDeniedError: 7:User not authorized.
```

I thought I was *Compute Engine default service account*, but that can't be right? I gave that service account the Owner role to test and it still fails.

Do I need to install gcloud on my Docker images on GKE so that I can authenticate as an service account with the correct roles before I start rails?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stackdriver Error reporting for Ruby, running on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019706/stackdriver-error-reporting-for-ruby-running-on-gke)

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is answered here:
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/authenticating-to-cloud-platform

You need to use the json key for the service account you'd like to use to access the API as a secret in your GKE cluster.